# Thymeleaf binding a selected value from a table

Tags: spring, list, spring-boot, data-binding, thymeleaf

I'm having a table with multiple elements that are generated from a List and every table element from that list has a button.By clicking that button there is a post submit request which should bind the values from that table data element to a @ModelAttribute object in spring boot.
The problem is that i'm able to map the whole list but I want to bind only the table element where the button was pressed.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <form th:action="@{/saveAd}" th:object="${object}" method="POST">
      <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
         <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
               <th>Image</th>
               <th>Title</th>
               <!-- <th style="width: 16.66%">Link</th> -->
               <th>Price</th>
               <th>City</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody id="myTable">

            <th:block th:each="element, itemStat: *{lista}">

               <tr
                  th:onclick="'javascript:rowClicked(\'' + *{lista[__${itemStat.index}__].url} + '\');'">
                  <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly"
                     th:name="?"
                     th:value="${element.getUrl()}" />
                  <td>
                     <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" th:name="img" th:value="${element.getImg()}" /> 
                     <img th:src="*{lista[__${itemStat.index}__].img}" class="size" name="img" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" th:name="?" th:value="${element.getTitle()}" />
                     <span th:text="*{lista[__${itemStat.index}__].title}"></span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" th:name="?" th:value="${element.getPrice()}" />
                     <span th:text="*{lista[__${itemStat.index}__].price}"></span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" th:name="?" th:value="${element.getCity()}" />
                     <span th:text="*{lista[__${itemStat.index}__].city}"></span>
                  </td>
                  <td><input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit"
                     value="Save"></td>
               </tr>
            </th:block>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </form>
</div>
```

The Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/saveAd", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveAd(@ModelAttribute("Value") ListCreationAutovitDto listCreationAutovitDto) {
        return "home";
    }
```

I have a hidden input type for every td which should map the values but i've tried naming it in different ways but i can't make it work.Are there any ways to bind only the values where the button was pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1: Make each `td` contain a `form` pointing to your controller method. Then bind the values you want to pass to the model by using hidden `input` fields in the form. Each button would then do a submit for the form it is in.

Idea 2: If you're mapping json to your java objects in your app, you can construct the json request body in JavaScript to contain only the stuff you want for that request